# Dynamically getting every check box and text box on a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following line of HTML

```
<input name="1" title="" id="1"  style="position: absolute; top: 155px; left: 687px; tabindex: 3000; z-order: 99;" type="checkbox" CHECKED="checked" runat="server" value="on"/>
```

What I want is a way to grab multiple checks boxes so I can set their tab index via the following javascript code:

```
var x = document.getElementById("1").tabIndex;  
document.getElementById("1").tabIndex = 1;
```

The code does work, but it only works for the sample line I placed. I tried putting my javascript into a for loop like so:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName("1");
var i;
for(i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i)
{
    var x = document.getElementsByName(i).tabIndex;  
    document.getElementsByName(i).tabIndex = 1;
}
```

I ran this by creating 4 copies of my HTML line of code and only changing its position in the CSS, but the code didn't work as I hoped.

Could someone please point out to me what it is I am doing wrong?

Comment: change this to `var x = document.getElementsByName(i.toString()).tabIndex;  
    document.getElementsByName(i.toString()).tabIndex = 1;`

Comment: As a side note: maybe you should consider naming your things differently "1" as an id is not that descriptive. It's curious that this even works - I've never seen number only ids, I never even thought of this :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elements` is a [*Collection of elements*](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp) in case of

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName("1");
```

So change your `for loop` to:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName("1");
var i;
for(i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i)
{
   elements[i].tabIndex = 1;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");`
```

and then iterate over the array and check for the types you want (ie. checkbox and text)

like so

```
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if(inputs[i].type == "checkbox" || inputs[i].type == "text") {
        //do whatever
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original code doesn't work because you need to refer to the `elements` array in the loop:

```
elements[i].tabIndex = 1;
```

That said, it doesn't make sense to use `getElementsByName` anyway, because surely all your textboxes and checkboxes won't have the same name.

You can use `querySelectorAll` to grab all text inputs and checkboxes like so:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text], input[type=checkbox]");
var i;
for(i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i)
{
    elements[i].tabIndex = 1;
}
```

If you need to support IE7 or lower, then you will have to get all inputs, then have a condition to filter textboxes and checkboxes.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var i;
for(i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i)
{
    if(elements[i].type == 'text' || elements[i].type == 'checkbox'){
        elements[i].tabIndex = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***tabIndex*** is an attribute in html.

```js
function set(){
var elements = document.getElementsByName("1");
var i;
for(i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i)
{
    elements[i].tabIndex = 1;
}
}
```

```html
<body onload="set()">

<input name="1" title="" id="1" tabIndex="3000"  style="position: absolute; top: 155px; left: 687px; z-order: 99;" type="checkbox" CHECKED="checked" runat="server" value="on"/>
<input name="1" title="" id="2" tabIndex="3001"  style="position: absolute; top: 155px; left: 687px; z-order: 100;" type="checkbox" runat="server" value="on"/>
<input name="1" title="" id="3" tabIndex="3002"  style="position: absolute; top: 155px; left: 687px; z-order: 101;" type="checkbox" runat="server" value="on"/>
<input name="1" title="" id="4" tabIndex="3003"  style="position: absolute; top: 155px; left: 687px; z-order: 102;" type="checkbox" runat="server" value="on"/>
</body>
```